# Error when trying to run .asm file on NASM on Ubuntu( A 64-bit code onto a 32-bit machine and 32-bit OS)

Tags: assembly

My system configuration is  Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E7500 @ 2.93GHz × 2 and also 32-bit OS. I am trying to run the following code. I used

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm
ld -o hello hello.o
```

It gives me a error

> ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `hello1.o' is incompatible with i386 output

Is there any way i could run a 64-bit code onto a 32-bit machine? I really need the solution.

code:

```
section .text
global _start
_start:

mov rax,01
mov rdi,01
mov rsi,msg1
mov rdx,len1
syscall

mov rax,660
xor rdx,rdx
syscall

section .data
msg1 db "hello world",0xa
len1 equ $-msg1
```

Comment: No, you can't run 64 bit code natively on a 32 bit OS. But that is a 64 bit cpu, so install a 64 bit OS on it. Otherwise, use an emulator (virtual machine).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run 64 bit assembly code on a 32 bit operating system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019179/run-64-bit-assembly-code-on-a-32-bit-operating-system)

Answer (score -1):

You could convert the code to 32-bit if you wanted to (trivial for your code sample):

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
mov eax,01
mov edi,01
mov esi,msg1
mov edx,len1
int 0x80

mov eax,660
xor edx,edx
int 0x80

section .data
msg1 db "hello world",0xa
len1 equ $-msg1
```

Then use the below commands:

```
nasm -f elf hello.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o hello hello.o
```

I tested to make sure there were no errors, I changed the syscall to int 0x80. I have never heard of the 660 syscall unfortunately. This above code does **not** print 'hello world' but it doesn't error either (it assembles).

The print string linux syscall is 4 (in eax), length in edx, message pointer in ecx, and stdout is 1 (ebx). Properly exiting is 1 in eax before syscall.

http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html has a good example of all of this in one place.